# How can I fit an image onto an iPhone template perfectly?

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I made a mock-up for mobile and saved it as a jpeg. Adobe fireworks has a library that contains an iPhone template and I wanted to fit my mock-up to fit perfectly inside it. I used transform and held shift to make it fit without it being squished. The issue is that I can only get the width right and not the height. My projects height is too tall for it to fit as well as the width. Is there any way to fit this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've described, you could try one of the following things:

### Use a Mask

Use a mask in Fireworks to hide the top and/or bottom of your image

1. Draw a rectangle the exact size of hole in the template
2. **Edit > Cut** to put the rectangle into your clipboard
3. Select your mockup image
4. **Edit > Paste as Mask** to mask your image

### Scale to fit vertically

Shift + Transform the mockup image to fit vertically inside the template, leaving empty space on the left and right sides

### Non-uniform Scale to fit vertically and horizontally

Transform the mockup image without Shift, and squish your design vertically to fit in the template

### Rework your mockup to fit

If none of the other options sound ideal, you could always re-work your mockup to fit into the dimensions of your device template.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your original design it is difficult to say what would be the best way to deal with this. You say your design is too tall so I am going to assume you do not want to crop it down.  (Can you add a pic so we can see?)

If possible I would probably look as adding to the sides of the design to make it wider so when you resized to the correct height it filled the width.

As previously said by @Vicki a mask or template would be of help here.

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal situation you would simply go back to your source file and if possible, slice it and save the slices as SVG. You could then keep the correct dimensions for most other elements and redo the background (if it is solid) by recreating it or if it is a pattern background by possibly recreating the pattern.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to the question. The question is about fitting a JPG mockup to the size of a specific template of a device—not recreating anything on an actual device... I think.

Comment: @CAI OP indicates that he has an original mockup and saved to JPEG. That is the problem since JPEG is not scalable. If possible saving the source as a SVG makes the content resizable and avoids the issue.